# Seleccionar filas correspondientes a un idUsuario

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy tratando de crear un query que solo seleccione los datos que tengan el respectivo idUsuario de mi base de datos, pero al momento en que mando a llamar el query me trae todos los datos, no soy muy experto en base de datos

Mi query es el seguiente:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE idEmitter 
IN ($us, $msg[0]) AND idReceiver IN ($msg[0], $us) ORDER BY sent ASC" ;
```

La variable `$us` esta asignada en el inicio de sesión, y la variable `$msg` esta en un foreach

Lo que quiero hacer es que me traiga todos los datos que vienen en mi base dependiendo de el id que traiga en la url

> localhost/talvez%20algo/chat/index.php?id=4

Esto es lo que debería de traer de mi base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo en mi sistema de mensajes trae todos los datos y solo debería de traer los que tienen nombre fernando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mibase de datos tengo los siguientes datos en cada fila

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi propósito, es crear un chat privado, en mi primera imagen muestro los datos de demon, cesar y fernando, pero como acabo de mencinar, quiero un chat privado, es decir :

Quiero que traiga los mensajes que se tengan en idEmitter y idReceiver dependiendo de los id's que tengan

```
1 con 3
3 con 1

3 con 4
4 con 3
```

Espero me haya dado a explicar

Este es el código de mi foreach, y en donde se muestra todo el chat

```
<?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
require_once '../functions.php';


$emit = obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us);

comprobarSession(); 

?>

<?php foreach ($emit as $msg): ?>   

<?php 

$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE idEmitter IN ($us) AND idReceiver IN ($msg[0], $us) ORDER BY sent ASC" ;

$run = $conexion->query($query);

while ($row = $run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
    //var_dump($row);

?>

        <div id="chat_data">
            <span style="color: green;"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> </span><br>
            <span style="color: brown;"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></span>
            <span style="float: right;"><?php echo fecha($row['sent']); ?></span>
        </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

> **Edicion**

La manera en que muestro la primer notificacion donde imprimo el ultimo mensaje es la siguiente

```
function obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us) {
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS m.idEmitter, m.nombre, m.message, m.sent, m.idReceiver
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN (SELECT idEmitter, idReceiver, max(idChat) AS idChat
FROM messages
WHERE seenEmpresa = 0
GROUP BY idEmitter, idReceiver) mm
ON m.idChat = mm.idChat
AND m.idEmitter = mm.idEmitter
AND m.idReceiver = mm.idReceiver
WHERE m.idReceiver = $us
AND seenEmpresa = 0");
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->fetchAll();
}
```

posteriormente uso un fichero llamado `notifiaciones.view.php` para mostrar la notificacion y obtener todos los datos de la funcion anterior

```
<?php session_start();

require 'extras/config.php';
require 'functions.php';

comprobarSession();

$conexion = conexion($bd_config);
if (!$conexion) {
    header('Location: error.php');
}

$mensajes = obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us);

if (!$mensajes) {
    $vacio = "<li>No cuentas con mensajes nuevos</li>";

    $guardadas = "<li>Los mensajes se han guardado en chats guardados</li>";
}

require "views/mensajes.view.php";
```

En siguiente imprimo todos los datos que trae la variable `$mensajes` y las imprimo en un html

```
    <?php foreach ($mensajes as $mensa): ?>

muchos mas div's

                  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $mensa['idEmitter']; ?>"><a href="<?php echo RUTA; ?>/chat/index.php?id=<?php echo $mensa['idEmitter']; ?>">

muchos div's
                </div><hr>
              <?php endforeach;?>
```

y asi es como mando el id del emisor por la url y en el apartado de chat quiero imprimirla

```
<?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
require_once '../functions.php';
require_once '../single.mensaje.php';

comprobarSession(); 

?>



<?php 

$query = "SELECT ue.idUsuario, ue.nombre, ur.nombre, c.sent, c.message FROM messages c
              INNER JOIN usuarios ue ON c.idEmitter = ue.idUsuario
              INNER JOIN usuarios ur ON c.idReceiver = ur.idUsuario
              WHERE (c.idEmitter = **AQUI QUIERO IMPRIMIR LA ID** AND c.idReceiver = $us)
              or (c.idEmitter = $us AND c.idReceiver = **AQUI QUIERO IMPRIMIR LA ID**)";

$run = $conexion->query($query);

while ($row = $run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
    var_dump($row);

?>

        <div id="chat_data">
            <span style="color: green;"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> </span><br>
            <span style="color: brown;"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></span>
            <span style="float: right;"><?php echo fecha($row['sent']); ?></span>
        </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

> **Manera en que intento recoger el id de la url**

Esta es la manera en que trato de obtener el id de la url

```
<?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
require_once '../functions.php';

comprobarSession(); 

$idEmitter = $_POST['id'];  <-- id de la url

?>



<?php 

$query = "SELECT ue.idUsuario, ue.nombre, ur.nombre, c.sent, c.message FROM messages c
              INNER JOIN usuarios ue ON c.idEmitter = ue.idUsuario
              INNER JOIN usuarios ur ON c.idReceiver = ur.idUsuario
              WHERE (c.idEmitter = $idEmitter <-- variable que contiene el id de la url previamente declarado AND c.idReceiver = $us)
              or (c.idEmitter = $us AND c.idReceiver = $idEmitter)";

$run = $conexion->query($query);

while ($row = $run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
    var_dump($row);

?>

        <div id="chat_data">
            <span style="color: green;"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> </span><br>
            <span style="color: brown;"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></span>
            <span style="float: right;"><?php echo fecha($row['sent']); ?></span>
        </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

> **Error que me marca en el chat**
>
> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez
>   empresa\chat\chat.php on line 8 NULL Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call
>   to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez
>   empresa\chat\chat.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\chat\chat.php on line 25

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si solo necesitas los que tengan cierto id, por que usas en tu where "AND idReceiver IN ($msg[0], $us)"?

Comment: @Rostan por que si lo pongo de esa manera me trae todo lo que demon envio a todos los demas id's y no al respectivo

Comment: Edita tu pregunta con las estructuras para así ayudarte.

Comment: @Rostan listo, la he editado

Comment: Pon el código del bucle for del que hablas en tu pregunta. Por un casual $us     o $msg[0] te vuelven true? Si es así tiene sentido que te devuelva todos los datos,  creo que sería más correcto algo como **where idEmitter = $us;**, pero pon el código del bucle y lo vemos

Comment: @Jakala, disculpa, no entendi lo que quieres que haga

Comment: Dices en tu pregunta que la variable msj está en un bucle foreach, puedes poner el código de ese bucle? Da la sensación de que esa variable no se esté asignando bien o la $us. Revisa que valores te está dando

Comment: @Jakala listo lo he editado

Comment: A ver, realmente el archivo `chat.php` no está recibiendo los parámetros. Tú estás enviando los parámetros a `index.php`, según muestras aquí:  `localhost/talvez%20algo/chat/index.php?id=4`  y el error te lo está dando en `chat.php` **Tienes una confusión de archivos**, ya que crees estar enviando los parámetros a `chat.php` cuando en realidad los estás mandando a `index.php` así nunca te va a funcionar. Pero como ya te he dicho varias veces, **este es otro problema distinto del problema original**. Si no lo resuelves corrigiendo eso, plantea otra pregunta por favor.

Comment: Además, tienes más errores en el código PHP. Para usar `FETCH_ASSOC` debe ser con `fetchAll` y no con `fetch` como lo estás haciendo. En el código de mi respuesta se muestra la forma correcta de hacerlo: **`$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`**
. Son varios errores relativos a tu código PHP que no tienen nada que ver con la pregunta original.

Comment: okok, verificare tu codigo y lo implementare de manera correcta, por lo pronto ya he generado otra pregunta

Comment: si le coloco el `fetchAll` me marca los siguientes errores  `Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\chat\chat.php on line 28` estos son datos del segundo codigo que tengo en mi pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo propondría un diseño parecido a este.

El código de más abajo aporta lo siguiente:

- **Evitar datos redundantes:** Una tabla dedicada a los usuarios del chat. De ese modo no tienes que andar repitiendo en la tabla `chat` sus nombres. Cuando haya miles o millones de registros, dicha tabla crecería de una forma impresionante y se haría pesada.
- **Seguridad:** Uso de PDO y consultas preparadas para evitar la Inyección SQL. Ya que tu código actual es vulnerable. Se aconseja no construir nunca consultas de esta forma: `$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE idEmitter IN ($us) AND idReceiver IN ($msg[0], $us) ORDER BY sent ASC" ;` todo lo que son variables, que vienen del exterior, deben ser sustituidos por marcadores de nombre `:nombre` o por marcadores de posición `?`.  Cuando puedas, sugiero que investigues un poco sobre la Inyección SQL.
- **Facilidad de lectura:** La lectura de los mensajes de todo el chat se hace con una sola línea de código, colocada dentro de un bucle: `$strHtml.='<span>'.$row["de"].': </span>'.$row["mensaje"].'<br />';`

La consulta que se usa para obtener el chat entre dos personas es esta:

```
    SELECT ue.nombre_usr de, ur.nombre_usr a, c.mensaje FROM  chat c 
    INNER JOIN chat_usuarios ue ON c.id_emitter=ue.id_usuario 
    INNER JOIN chat_usuarios ur ON c.id_reciever=ur.id_usuario
    WHERE    (c.id_emitter=:usr1 AND c.id_reciever=:usr2) 
          or (c.id_emitter=:usr2 AND c.id_reciever=:usr1)";
```

El código muestra una forma de presentar los datos. Eres libre de implementar esa parte como quieras. Si quieres combinar colores diferentes para el que envía y el que recibe, puedes usar algo del tipo `odd`, aplicando reglas CSS. Como se hace por ejemplo con las tablas, que muestran una línea de un color y otra de otro. Aunque puede que el emisor escriba más de un mensaje seguido... en ese caso puedes aplicar una clase ligada a usuario1, y usuario2, por ejemplo y aplicar estilos en base a eso.

Aquí vamos:

#### `Código:`  [`Ver Demo`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/93td-mqiy)

```
<?php

require "util/public_db_info.php";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);

/**
 *  Crear tablas
 *  e Insertar Datos de prueba
*/

$sql = 
       "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat (
            id_chat       INT PRIMARY KEY,
            id_emitter    INT,
            id_reciever   INT,
            mensaje       TEXT
            );

        DELETE FROM  chat; //¡CUIDADO! Esto es sólo de prueba

        INSERT INTO chat (id_chat, id_emitter, id_reciever, mensaje) VALUES 
        (1,1,2,'Hola Pedro'),
        (2,2,1,'Hola César'),
        (3,1,2,'¿Cómo estás?'),
        (4,2,1,'Bien'),
        (5,1,3,'Hola Juan'),
        (6,3,1,'Hola César, aquí Juan'),
        (7,1,3,'¿Cómo estás Juan?'),
        (8,3,1,'Bien, César')        ;";


$stmt=$pdo->query($sql);

$sql = 
       "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat_usuarios (
            id_usuario    INT PRIMARY KEY,
            nombre_usr    VARCHAR(50)
         );

         DELETE FROM  chat_usuarios;  //¡CUIDADO! Esto es sólo de prueba

         INSERT INTO chat_usuarios (id_usuario, nombre_usr) VALUES  
          (1,'César'),
          (2,'Pedro'),
          (3,'Juan')
          ;";

$stmt=$pdo->query($sql);

$sql="
        SELECT ue.nombre_usr de, ur.nombre_usr a, c.mensaje FROM  chat c 
        INNER JOIN chat_usuarios ue ON c.id_emitter=ue.id_usuario 
        INNER JOIN chat_usuarios ur ON c.id_reciever=ur.id_usuario
        WHERE     (c.id_emitter=:usr1 AND c.id_reciever=:usr2) 
               or (c.id_emitter=:usr2 AND c.id_reciever=:usr1)";



/**
 *  Pruebas 
 *  En el código  se usa  PDO y  consultas preparadas
*/


$usr1=1;
$usr2=2;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("usr1",$usr1);
$stmt->bindParam("usr2",$usr2);
$stmt ->execute();

$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
imprimir ($arrDatos);


$usr1=1;
$usr2=3;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("usr1",$usr1);
$stmt->bindParam("usr2",$usr2);
$stmt ->execute();
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

imprimir ($arrDatos);

$pdo = null;


//Una función para mostrar los datos
function imprimir($arrDatos)
{

    if ($arrDatos)
    {
        echo "<hr />SE ENCONTRARON  ".count($arrDatos). " REGISTROS<br /><hr />";
        /**
         *  Construímos los datos  de forma limpia
        */
        $strHtml='CHAT:<br />';    
        foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
        {
            $strHtml.='<span>'.$row["de"].': </span>'.$row["mensaje"].'<br />';
        }
        echo $strHtml;
    }
}

?>
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
Prueba de chat entre César y Pedro

SE ENCONTRARON 4 REGISTROS
CHAT:
César: Hola Pedro
Pedro: Hola César
César: ¿Cómo estás?
Pedro: Bien


Prueba de chat entre César y Juan

SE ENCONTRARON 4 REGISTROS
CHAT:
César: Hola Juan
Juan: Hola César, aquí Juan
César: ¿Cómo estás Juan?
Juan: Bien, César
```

Comment: he tratado de integrar tu respuesta a mi codigo, pero no lo he conseguido, he batalladoun poco ya que son dos usuarios diferentes, te puedo contactar por email?

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos si quieres puedes dejar comentarios con el problema que estás teniendo. Lo veré mañana por la tarde. Para mí es hora de dormir y estaré ocupado mañana todo el día. Para ayudar a aclarar dudas: se ha creado una tabla `usuarios` y la tabla `chat` sólo hace una relación entre el emisor y el receptor mediante el id de cada uno en la tabla usuarios. Mediante ese id se sabe quien emite y quien recibe.

Comment: Bueno, es que el ID que necesito lo traigo por la URL pero no logro conseguir obtenerlo dentro del query y ya probé de mucha maneras usando `_GET` y nada

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos para obtener la id que pasas en la URL, si la URL es parecida a esto: `localhost/talvez%20algo/chat/index.php?id=4` puedes obtener el valor de `id` haciendo algo así: `$id=$_POST["id"]`. Pero  si quieres un chat entre dos personas debes pasar las id del emisor y del receptor. Tu URL debería ser más o menos: `localhost/talvez%20algo/chat/index.php?id_emisor=1&id_receptor=2`  y luego recuperas: `$usr1=$_POST["id_emisor"]; $usr2=$_POST["id_receptor"];`

Comment: El ID del receptor la paso por medio del inicio de sesión, la guardo en una variable y la asignó en el query, pero el ID del emisor que es la que traigo en la URL siguo sin poder obtenerla aún usando tu ejemplo que me diste

Comment: ¿Dónde recoges el id, en un formulario? ¿Cuál es el método de ese formulario? ¿Así tampoco funciona: `$_GET["id"]` o así `$_REQUEST["id"]`?

Comment: No, no recojo el ID en ningún formulario, sé que debes estar muy ocupado pero este es el link dónde tengo mi proyecto https://mega.nz/#%25212wsFgA5T%2521RoidaAEKQZsesMYjqDLnW4--KFuuTRy1F2ak-vaeIvc solo me falta la parte del chat para concluirlo

Comment: Ahora mismo no podría revisar un proyecto completo @CesarGutierrezDavalos . Bastaría con que indiques la parte del código en que envías los datos. Es extraño que no recoja los datos usando POST. ¿Probaste con REQUEST y con GET como indico en el anterior comentario?

Comment: Editare mi pregunta con la forma en que tomo los datos

Comment: LISTO, LA HE EDITADO

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos mi respuesta fue elaborada con el objetivo de mostrarte una posibilidad de consultar a la base de datos y obtener los mensajes de chat entre un emisor y un receptor. Recuperar un dato posteando mediante `$_POST` o mediante `$_GET` es una de las cosas más sencillas que se hacen en PHP. Si no puedes recuperar dichos datos es posible que no los estés pasando bien. Responder a ese **nuevo** problema sería como responder dos preguntas en una, lo cual no responde al formato de este sitio y dificulta encontrar una solución. Sugiero que plantees una nueva pregunta al respecto.

Comment: Me extraña que no puedas recuperar el valor del id haciendo algo como esto: `$_GET["id"]` o esto `$_POST["id"]`. O quizá no estás poniendo eso donde deberías, es decir, en el último código de tu pregunta editada.

Comment: Pues primero lo intento pasar a una variable ej $idEmitter = $_GET["id"]  y no lo acepta después trato de imprimirla directo en el query de mil y un maneras y tampoco funciona

Comment: Pero... **¿dónde lo estás haciendo?** Según esto compartido en tu pregunta: `localhost/talvez%20algo/chat/index.php?id=4` si haces `$idEmitter = $_GET["id"]`  o `$idEmitter = $_POST["id"]`  en el archivo **`index.php`**  debería almacenarte en la variable el valor `4` en este caso.  **¿Lo estás haciendo en `index.php`  o en otra parte?** El archivo que está recibiendo los datos es `index.php`

Comment: en efecto lo estoyhaciendo en `index.php`, acabo de mostrar como la intento obtener

Comment: No, no. Así no: `$idEmitter = $_POST['idEmitter'];` Si la URL es así: `localhost/talvez%20algo/chat/index.php?id=4` no puedes poner `idEmitter` dentro de los corchetes del POST, sino que debes poner  `id`. Es decir: **`$idEmitter = $_POST['id'];`** El identificador que va entre los corchetes es el que haya después del signo `?` en la URL, `id` en este caso.

Comment: Si, en mi edición lo puse de esa manera sin darme cuenta pero aunque lo ponga con ID no lo toma

Comment: `id`  en **minúscula**, tal y como aparece en la URL. Eso debes hacerlo en el archivo `index.php` que se encuentra en la carpeta `.../talvez%20algo/chat/`. Si no funciona, debes formular otra pregunta dando más detalles sobre el contexto del problema. De esta manera es imposible encontrar una solución.

Comment: acabo de colocar mas cosas

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu error radica en el **$msg[0]**, al ponerle un índice no estas dejando que itere correctamente tu foreach, intenta simplemente dejando **$msg**, asi implícitamente la variable se cargara con el siguiente valor.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE idEmitter IN ($us) AND idReceiver IN ($msg, $us) ORDER BY sent ASC" ;
```

Espero mi respuesta te haya ayudado, ya que mi dominio de php no es alto. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por querer ayudar, pero el error, no es ese, si le quito el [0] del arreglo, este marca un error

Comment: Mm ok, y si al ser un índice mejor no iteras con una variable en vez del 0!? así como un $msg[i], y dentro del foreach vas aumentando el valor de i.

Comment: he editado mi pregunta con mas codigo y mejor explicado, creo yo, espero me puedas ayudar